# Get image original width & height in actionscript

Tags: actionscript

I use AS3 in Flex 3 to create new image and seem unable to get the exact size of the original image. percentHeight & percentWidth to 100 can do the job, but limitation in ObjectHandlers require me to set the image scale in pixel.

Any solution?

Comment: How do you create this new image? From a Bitamp?

Answer (score 6):

**Note:** this is also applicable for displaying Image original dimension without ObjectHandler control, just remove those lines that are not applicable.

After struggle hours for solution, I found my own answer thru in actionscript forum, in fact, only one solution, I surprise there was no such topic elsewhere.

```
private function init():void {
    var image:Image = new Image();
    image.source = "http://www.colorjack.com/software/media/circle.png";
    image.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
    /* wait for completion as Image control is asynchronous,
     * which mean ObjectHandler will attempt to load asap
     * and you are not able to get the correct dimension for scaling.
     * EventListener fixed that.
     */
    this.addChild(image);
    //whenever you scale ObjectHandler control, the image is always fit by 100%
    image.percentHeight = 100;
    image.percentWidth = 100;
}

private function imageLoaded(e:Event):void{
    var img:Image = e.target as Image;
    trace("Height ", img.contentHeight);
    trace("Width ", img.contentWidth);
    var oh:ObjectHandles = new ObjectHandles();
    oh.x = 200;
    oh.y = 200;
    oh.height = img.contentHeight;
    oh.width = img.contentWidth;
    oh.allowRotate = true;
    oh.autoBringForward = true;
    oh.addChild(img);
    genericExamples.addChild(oh);
}
```